# Accessing child nodein an xml in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

How to retrieve the value of type in the below XML

```
 <info><category>Flip</category><info>2</info><type>Tree</type></info>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as E
e = E.parse("test.xml")
print(e.find("type").text)
```

Using minidom:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
d = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
print(d.getElementsByTagName("type")[0].firstChild.data)
```

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(open("test.xml"))
print(soup.find("type").text)
```